# How to deploy to heroku simple website without package.json

Tags: heroku, git-push

I havent used any languages that heroku support, like node.js. Its simple HTML, CSS website. There is no package.json file. When I'm trying to push to heroku my website it says:

```
!     No default language could be detected for this app.
        HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
        See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks!
!     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku isn't meant for hosting static sites. But if you must, you can trick it into think you have a php website and it will use that buildpack.

https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/deploy-static-site-heroku